# Why does python change every lists when indexing a list of empty list?

Tags: python, list

I created a list of 3 empty lists:

```
>>> l = [[]]*3
>>> l
[[], [], []]
```

then added an item in the second one:

```
>>> l[1].append("j")
```

but it added it on every lists:

```
>>> l
[['j'], ['j'], ['j']]
```

why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)  You don't have a "list of lists" here, you have a list of *list*, singular.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the `[[]]*3` operator adds 3 times the same list as a reference ; so modifying one list modifies every others.

To create 3 empty different lists:

```
>>> l = [[] for r in range(3)]
>>> l[1].append("j")
>>> l
[[], ['j'], []]
```

Comment: Yes, Im going to go ahead and say you are correct. Because if you manually enter sublists and try and append it works as intended. ```l = [[],[],[]]
l[0].extend("j")
print(l)```